# Why is my screen flow not contextualizing to the current record?

Tags: visual-workflow, related-list, screen-flow, relatedrecord

I'm working on a very simple screen flow and I need your help...

I have a `contract` object that has a `tutor` field, which refers to a **contact** record. On my `contact` page, I want my screen flow to include a field that sums up the number of open contracts where that contact is registered as a tutor.

[image]

Right now, the field should show 1, but it shows *all* the open contracts across the db. The field that says **"Nombre d'apprenants suivis actuellement: 353,00"**
[image]

In the get record, I'm trying to filter the contract where the id in the `tutor` field matches the id of the current contact record I'm viewing ([like mentioned here](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.flow_pause_recordassoc.htm&type=5)), to no avail.

[image: I have tried matching the contact id with the one in the field (like mentioned here), to no avail]

Can you help me figure it out? Thank you!

Comment: Can you confirm what is that get records filtering?

Comment: @SaiPraveenKakkirala thank you for taking a look, I've edited my question hoping to make it better.

Comment: Can you please help me on the filter condition you used in get records because I am not familiar with the language you are using in the flow. I just need translation for that get records filter. How are you passing current recordId to the flow?

Comment: @SaiPraveenKakkirala of course, the "select_tuteur_c" is a lookup field, the operator is "equals" and the value is "$Flow.CurrentRecord" like here https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.flow_pause_recordassoc.htm&type=5.  Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess the issue is in `getrecord` element in the flow. In the place of `$Flow.CurrentRecord` can you try creating a variable of name `recordId` of type Text and check Available for Input as shown below.

[image]

Now edit your lightning page under your flow and check the checkbox `pass recordId into this variable` give the input as shown below.

[image]

You can refer the [example](https://www.levelupsalesforce.com/get-current-record-id-in-flow) for the same.

Comment: Should the input variable not be called `recordId` (lower case first letter)? Also, this variable can be the whole record or the ID only as desired.

Comment: @PhilW, Yes it can be recordId. We are just passing the Id from the record as the variable is of type Text and we just need Id of the Record I guess. So added it as Text.

Comment: The documentation says to use `recordId`. Are you saying this is case insensitive?

Comment: In this scenario We can use anything because we are passing the variable to the flow from the lightning page as shown above. I tried using both and both worked as expected.

Comment: Thank you! You taught me something and saved my day! Worked perfectly of course :D

Comment: Oh, OK, yes, you talk about passing `recordId` in explicitly. Ignore my concerns!